# How to change the number of images to use for training and evaluating in tensorflow2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, mnist, loaddata, tensorflow2.0

The Fashion-MNIST dataset automatically returns 60,000 images for training and 10,000 images for evaluation.  How do I change those numbers?

Here is my [`colab`](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/keras/basic_classification.ipynb) source code and the relevant part is:

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: You can do it inside tensorflow data api pipeline, or simply concatenate numpy arrays and then split them in any proportion you need

Answer (score 4):

## 1. Tensorflow Datasets

Since `TF2.0` it is advised to use `tf.data` API with `tf.keras`. `tf.data.Dataset` as part of the aforementioned allows you to easily carry various operations on your data like image augmentation (e.g. rotation/shifting) via `map` calls (you can find other possibilities [in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)).

[Tensorflow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) is a part of Tensorflow's ecosystem and allows you easier data downloading (various ready datasets are present, **including Fashion MNIST**, [see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/datasets) for available options) and getting it in `tf.data.Dataset` form already.

Using this snippet:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train, test = tfds.load("fashion_mnist", as_supervised=True)
```

Will download data and automatically split it into `test` and `train` (same as the Keras equivalent, except for data type).

You can create your own datasets builders, though usually call to `tfds.load` will be enough for standard operations.

## Custom splits

Now if you want different splitting (not the default `60000` train and `10000` test), you may define it using `tfds.Split` object. By default, each of the provided datasets (so your Fashion MNIST is included) provides default `tfds.Split.TRAIN` and `tfds.Split.TEST` (some provide `tfds.Split.VALID` as well).

Those default splits can be further divided into subparts in various ways:

Split one of `TEST` or `TRAIN` into `N` parts. Code below will only download 30.000 images from TRAIN and 5.000 images from test:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_half_1, train_half_2 = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(2)
test1, test2, test3, test4 = tfds.Split.TEST.subsplit(4)

train_first_half = tfds.load("fashion-mnist", split=train_half_1)
test_second_quarter = tfds.load("fashion-mnist", split=test2)
```

In similar way you can take `N` percents of each split:

```
first_10_percent = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[:10])
```

Or you could even combine splits in order to get more data like this (you could than further split this data however you like:

```
train_and_test = tfds.Split.TRAIN + tfds.Split.TEST
```

## 2. Keras

Keras loads data in `numpy` format and though it's not advised and does not allow one to perform many operations with simple `map` you could split those using [standard Python's slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation):

```
import tensorflow as tf

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

# First 10.000 elements from train
X_train_subset = X_train[:10000]

# Elements from 1000 to 5000 from test labels
y_test_subset = y_test[1000:5000]

# Elements from 8500 to the end of test data
X_test_subset = X_test[8500:]
```

On the other hand it might be much more convenient to work with `numpy` arrays instead of `tf.data.Dataset` for certain applications (especially more non-standard ones) so the choice is yours.

Comment: Here is some code to do this: (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))